# Does Thunderbolt 3 require a special cable?

Tags: usb-3, thunderbolt

There are laptops that ship with Thunderbolt 3 which uses a USB-C connection. Is a special cable required for Thunderbolt 3 or will any USB-C cable work?

Comment: Yes; Thunderbolt 3 cables are not USB 3.1 C cables just compatible with it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no. I am still looking into this myself, but what I can see so far is either:

- USB 3.1 cable for USB 3.1
- Passive thunderbolt for 20Gbit/sec thunderbolt or USB 3.1 (at USB speeds)
- Active thunderbolt for 40Gbit/sec thunderbolt. Assumed also compatible with  USB 3.1 at USB speeds.

The first two might be the same cable. I only found [this source](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2486078,00.asp) on that though:
The simplest cables are passive and made of copper metal. **Passive Thunderbolt 3 cables are identical to USB-C cables** and plug into Thunderbolt 3 or USB-C ports.

Found sources thus far:

- https://thunderbolttechnology.net/tech/faq
  What is the difference between Thunderbolt 3 and USB-C?
  Thunderbolt 3 is a superset solution which includes USB 3.1 (10Gbps)
- Same source:
  Can I connect USB devices to a Thunderbolt 3 port?
  Yes, Thunderbolt 3 ports are fully compatible with USB devices and cables.
- Sales text on a [0.5m Thunderbolt 3 (40Gbps) USB-C Cable](http://www.startech.com/uk/Cables/thunderbolt-3-cables/thunderbolt-3-40gbps-usb-c-cable~TBLT34MM50CM):
  Compatible with Thunderbolt and USB devices. Supports 40Gbps data throughput.
- http://arstechnica.co.uk/gadgets/2015/06/thunderbolt-3-embraces-usb-type-c-connector-doubles-bandwidth-to-40gbps/
  Thunderbolt 3 is backed by Intel's new Alpine Ridge controller. USB 3.1 support is provided by integrating a USB 3.1 host controller into Alpine Ridge.
- same source:
  At launch, there'll be one **passive** Thunderbolt 3 cable that supports Thunderbolt, USB 3.1, and DisplayPort 1.2, but with a max bandwidth of only 20Gbps. Intel confirms that this passive cable will be a standard, cheap USB Type-C cable.

Comment: This review for a thunderboilt-3 NAS is just out. (http://www.anandtech.com/show/10248/thunderbolt-3-in-action-akitio-thunder3-duo-pro-das-review/1). The NAS is not as interesting, but it describes some of the background for thunderbolt. It might be worth reading.

Answer (score 3):

There will be 3 kinds of different Thunderbolt cables as summarized in this slide from Intel below at IDF 2015:

[image: IDF 2015 : thunderbolt cables]

> **Passive lower cost cables will support Thunderbolt™ at 20Gb/s**
>
> - Low cost cables will be adequate for many Thunderbolt devices
> - Lengths up    to 2.0m
>
> **Thunderbolt active cables will support Thunderbolt at 40Gb/s**
>
> - Needed for high-performance docking with 4K displays and storage, and    enthusiast-level external graphics
> - Lengths up to 2.0m
>
> **Optical Cables will support Thunderbolt at 40Gb/s**
>
> - Targeted for 2016 with lengths up to 60m